# How does .NET optimize methods that return a Structure value?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Consider a method that returns a Structure, like this:

```
Public Function DoWork() As MyStructure

    Return New MyStructure(1.5, 1.7, 1.1, 55.9)

End Function
```

In this case, does .NET create and initialize a `MyStructure` value *once*, or *twice*?

**EDIT:** My hunch is that a call to `DoWork` must involve .NET pushing the return value on the stack right from the outset. Otherwise, how would `Return` get anything back to the calling code? So that's the first initialization I'm talking about.

The second initialization would be at the `Return` statement, where arguments *1.5, 1.7, 1.1, 55.9* initialize a new `MyStructure` value. On `Return`, .NET would then overwrite the existing value on the Stack with the new return value.

The thing is, I know very little about how .NET works under the hood. My conception of how Stacks work is based on vague recollections of trying to code in Pascal, under DOS, in the early 90s. I have no idea how .NET/Windows does things these days!

Comment: I recently tested both JITs for avoiding structure copies. I did not test function returns, I forgot about them. But inside of a method almost everything about structs is translated literally as you write it. Very little copy avoidance even in obvious cases. So don't get your hopes up, not a lot of optimizations in the .NET JITs.

Comment: If it were twice, which would be the second time (after the `New`)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders maybe the result of the new is first written to a fresh stack location and only then the return would be executed by copying the temporary to the return value location. I think that would be what a non-optimizing JIT naturally would do.

Comment: @usr: thanks. I think the OP should specify that in the question for those of us who are a bit IL-challenged

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm afraid I don't know, I am IL one of those IL challenged! My hunch is that .NET has to initialize `MyStructure` as soon as the method is entered. The second initialization would occur on Return. I'm 99% sure that's how it goes in VBA... .NET is a whole new world for me.

Comment: What you just said in the comment is what I'd like you to say in the question :-)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I went a step further and tried to describe how I think things work. Would be nice to know for sure of course.

Comment: I understand why you're asking this question, but the only reasonable answer is still "profile and see". The key point is "is this fast enough for me?", not "is .NET smart enough?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have a look at the generated machine code to see what happens.  You first need to change an option to ensure the optimizer is enabled, Tools > Options > Debugging > General > untick the "Suppress JIT optimization" checkbox.  Switch to the Release build.  Set a breakpoint on the DoWork call and when it hits use Debug > Windows > Disassembly to see the generated machine code.

I'll noodle a little bit about what you see.  Your instinct is correct, only returning simple scalar values is efficient, they fit in a CPU register.  Not this structure, the caller method must reserve space on its stack frame so the callee can store the structure there.  It passes a pointer to that reserved space.  In other words, there's no real difference if you had declared this method as `Public Sub DoWork(ByRef retval As MyStructure)`.

Only other way this code can be optimized is by inlining the Function.  The x86 jitter does not do that, it is picky about methods returning structs.  The x64 jitter does in fact inline the method, but then does an absolutely horrible job with it.  It still reserves the space for the return value and then generates lots and lots of needless initialization and value moving code.  Quite atrocious.  This jitter was rewritten for VS2015 (project name RyuJIT), I don't have it installed yet to see if it does a better job at it.

Basic conclusion to draw: this code isn't optimized.  Structures work well when you pass them ByVal.  Don't let this cramp your style, we're talking nanoseconds here.

Comment: Didn't you just describe that it *is* in fact optimized? It sounds like the struct isn't copied at all.

Comment: Erm, not sure where you got that.  You'd expect no copy and ByRef behavior, the x64 jitter fumbles that.

Comment: Well, you said - `Not this structure, the caller method must reserve space on its stack frame so the callee can store the structure there. It passes a pointer to that reserved space. In other words, there's no real difference if you had declared this method as Public Sub DoWork(ByRef retval As MyStructure).` I understand that as meaning "it is passed directly to the stack space allocated by the caller". Maybe you meant "both the caller and the callee have to allocate stack space and then the callee copies to the caller's stack space"?

Comment: That's not what I meant.  Copying only occurs when the structure is too large, it isn't.

Comment: I just tried it. The good news are that small structs are passed and returned as registers in RyuJIT. The bad news is that any operation on those values copies them to stack slots. After inlining the code can become worse because the register passing is now gone. And you find gems like `mov dword ptr [rsp+30h],ecx ; mov dword ptr [rsp+30h],1003h `. Or a `cmp &x, x` followed by nothing that would use it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your efforts here, and for instructions on how to drill down to the machine code. I've just started to replicate what you're seeing yourself. Fascinating stuff. Unlike the 80s/90s, I'm going to have to learn to just let .NET do its thing and stop worrying about premature optimization. Next on the list is something that *is* worth worrying about - COM interop and those pesky RCWs. That should be fun...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what is done in IL for struct of a BCL type it seems to be created only once.
Example with [Size.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.truncate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public static Size Truncate(SizeF value)
{
    return new Size((int)value.Width, (int)value.Height);
}
```

```cs
.method public hidebysig static 
valuetype System.Drawing.Size Truncate (
    valuetype System.Drawing.SizeF 'value'
) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x169d6
    // Code size 22 (0x16)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarga.s 'value'
    IL_0002: call instance float32 System.Drawing.SizeF::get_Width()
    IL_0007: conv.i4
    IL_0008: ldarga.s 'value'
    IL_000a: call instance float32 System.Drawing.SizeF::get_Height()
    IL_000f: conv.i4
    IL_0010: newobj instance void System.Drawing.Size::.ctor(int32, int32)
    IL_0015: ret
} // end of method Size::Truncate
```

You can see at `IL_0010` the `newobj` opcode and it's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states :

> Creates a new object or a **new instance of a value type**, pushing an object reference (type O) onto the evaluation stack.

Comment: True, but this only describes the "virtual machine" - the key point is how the IL is translated to machine code. If you went by IL alone, you'd think that everything is done on the stack in .NET, which simply isn't true.